# How to get the value of an api key in CDK (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-cdk

I have this problem. I want to create an API Gateway that can only be accessed with an API key - that part is done. Now I want to store the value of the API key in secrets manager. I am able to store hardcoded values in the secrets manager but not the actual value of the API keys. The code for creating the api keys is:

```
const key = api.addApiKey('ApiKey');
```

and I am able to store a hardcoded value in secrets manager with:

```
const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'Secret', {
      description: "Secret ",
      secretName: "secret",
      generateSecretString: {
        secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({"api_key" : "some_value"}),
        generateStringKey: "string_key",
      }
    });
```

How can i store the api key instead of the hardcoded value?

Comment: Is this custom [Lambda rotation function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html), what your are looking for?

Comment: I basically just want to pass the api key i created to secretsmanager insted of "some_value"

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-secretsmanager-readme.html) you can find examples for reference.

Comment: Thanks alot, but I already looked at those examples. They dont say anything about how you store the api key in secrets manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way we can extract the api key value without a custom resource.

But this can easily be done the other way round. we first need to generate the secret and use that value to create api key.

```
    const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'Secret', {
        generateSecretString: {
            generateStringKey: 'api_key',
            secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username: 'web_user' }),
            excludeCharacters: ' %+~`#$&*()|[]{}:;<>?!\'/@"\\',
        },
    });
    this.restApi.addApiKey('ApiKey', {
        apiKeyName: `web-app-key`,
        value: secret.secretValueFromJson('api_key').toString(),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Great! Glad i could help.

Comment: btw is there a way to only generate a new secret if the secret name does not already exist in secrets manager? E.g. when you do cdk destroy and the cdk deploy. I am also running into some problems with strange mismatch between the API key and the api key stored in the secrets manager - over time.

Comment: I think cdk destroy follow by cdk deploy will fail, because secrets are actually stored with the same name in aws for at least 7 days after deletion

Comment: @smallbirds as secret manager resource doesn't get deleted right away, issue always exists with secret manager, you can passing a different `secretName` attribute each time you destroy and recreate. or pass different id `Secret` which is what is used to derive Name of the secret.